# Signature Capture within PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, electronic-signature

I am attempting to add signature capture functionality to a PhoneGap application. I have found a few options such as signature capture 2.8.1 (http://androidapp.lisisoft.com/apps-android-phone/108585-biz.binarysolutions.signature.html) and Thomas J. Bradley's signature Pad javascript plugin (http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/). The first works pretty well on the android device but requires a license. The second works well in a browser but does not work at all when run within my PhoneGap application.

Does anyone have a suggestion of an open source signature capture application that will work within PhoneGap? Or has anyone had success tweaking Thomas J. Bradleys signature pad to work within phonegap?

UPDATE: Thomas J. Bradley signature pad only works with android SDK 10/ Android 2.3 and higher.

Comment: I know of a developer who wrote a Plugin for the signature capture 2.8.1 but did not release it as open source. So it can be done.

Answer (score 10):

Try using  [jSignature](http://www.unbolt.net/jSignature/)

Comment: See newer demo page of jSignature here: http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/demo/

Comment: This is the main github repo that's actually updated https://github.com/brinley/jSignature

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/triceam/Mobile-Signature-Capture

try using this trecidesign code.I think it can help you.