# Add digital signature pad in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In my app I want to add digital signature pad.
When I click on button say sign then pop up of signature pad should be get open and when I click on save signature should get save in image format.
I have refer the following links but I am not able to get that ...
Please Explain me what should I do. Thanks in advance..
Links are :

1: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121136-simFla.ux.plugins.signaturePad

2: http://j-query.blogspot.in/2011/02/sencha-touch-ipad-signature-javascript.html

Comment: Use this link which will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946061/signature-capture-within-phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please refer this link to use canvas github plugin for digital signature [click link](https://github.com/jsphkhan/rialabphonegap/tree/master/android/HTML5%20Canvas%20toDataUrl%28%29)
Hope this help. good luck ...